# Unexpected T_Variable !! Have checked coding twice

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am making a script to create a CSV file to pull data out of ze DB. When I run the script it comes back with unexpected T_Variable on line 173 @ '$body'. I have checked it a few times and also looked up other incidents with this issue.  Perhaps I am overlooking (lack of sleep).  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', '******', '********');
mysql_select_db('*****');
$id_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `id` FROM  `leads` WHERE  `status` =  'Passed' AND  `campaign_id` =  '22d0cf4f-0f81-28b1-d8dc-4f06bd1d8ee'");
$id = mysql_fetch_row($id_query);
echo $id[0];

$first_name_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `first_name` 
FROM  `leads` 
WHERE  `id` =  '$id[0]'");
$first_name = mysql_fetch_row($first_name_query);
$url_first_name = $first_name[0];
echo $url_first_name;

$last_name_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `last_name`
FROM  `leads`
WHERE  `id` =  '$id[0]'");
$last_name = mysql_fetch_row($last_name_query);
$url_last_name = $last_name[0];
echo $url_last_name;

$phone_home_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `phone_home`
FROM  `leads`
WHERE  `id` =  '$id[0]'");
$phone_home = mysql_fetch_row($phone_home_query);
$url_phone_home = $phone_home[0];
echo $url_phone_home;

$primary_address_street_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `primary_address_street`
FROM  `leads`
WHERE  `id` =  '$id[0]'");
$primary_address_street = mysql_fetch_row($primary_address_street_query);
$url_primary_address_street = $primary_address_street[0];
echo $url_primary_address_street;

$primary_address_city_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `primary_address_city`
FROM  `leads`
WHERE  `id` =  '$id[0]'");
$primary_address_city = mysql_fetch_row($primary_address_city_query);
$url_primary_address_city = $primary_address_city[0];
echo $url_primary_address_city;

$primary_address_state_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `primary_address_state`
FROM  `leads`
WHERE  `id` =  '$id[0]'");
$primary_address_state = mysql_fetch_row($primary_address_state_query);
$url_primary_address_state = $primary_address_state[0];
echo $url_primary_address_state;

$primary_address_postalcode_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `primary_address_postalcode`
FROM  `leads`
WHERE  `id` =  '$id[0]'");
$primary_address_postalcode = mysql_fetch_row($primary_address_postalcode_query);
$url_primary_address_postalcode = $primary_address_postalcode[0];
echo $url_primary_address_postalcode;

$dateofbirth_c_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `dateofbirth_c`
FROM  `leads_cstm`
WHERE  `id_c` =  '$id[0]'");
$dateofbirth_c = mysql_fetch_row($dateofbirth_c_query);
$url_dateofbirth_c = $dateofbirth_c[0];
echo $url_dateofbirth_c;

$gender_c_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `gender_c`
FROM  `leads_cstm`
WHERE  `id_c` =  '$id[0]'");
$gender_c = mysql_fetch_row($gender_c_query);
$g2 = substr($gender,0,1);
$url_gender = $g2[0];
echo $url_gender_c;

$testblood_c_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `testblood_c`
FROM  `leads_cstm`
WHERE  `id_c` =  '$id[0]'");
$testblood_c = mysql_fetch_row($testblood_c_query);
$b2 = substr($testblood_c,0,1);
$url_testblood_c = $b2[0];
echo $url_testblood_c;

$physicianlastname_c_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `physicianlastname_c`
FROM  `leads_cstm`
WHERE  `id_c` =  '$id[0]'");
$physicianlastname_c = mysql_fetch_row($physicianlastname_c_query);
$url_physicianlastname_c = $physicianlastname_c[0];
echo $url_physicianlastname_c;

$physicianfirstname_c_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `physicianfirstname_c`
FROM  `leads_cstm`
WHERE  `id_c` =  '$id[0]'");
$physicianfirstname_c = mysql_fetch_row($physicianfirstname_c_query);
$url_physicianfirstname_c = $physicianfirstname_c[0];
echo $url_physicianfirstname_c;

$physiciancity_c_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `physiciancity_c`
FROM  `leads_cstm`
WHERE  `id_c` =  '$id[0]'");
$physiciancity_c = mysql_fetch_row($physiciancity_c_query);
$url_physiciancity_c = $physiciancity_c[0];
echo $url_physiciancity_c;

$physicianstate_c_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `physicianstate_c`
FROM  `leads_cstm`
WHERE  `id_c` =  '$id[0]'");
$physicianstate_c = mysql_fetch_row($physicianstate_c_query);
$url_physicianstate_c = $physicianstate_c[0];
echo $url_physicianstate_c;

$physicianphone_c_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `physicianphone_c`
FROM  `leads_cstm`
WHERE  `id_c` =  '$id[0]'");
$physicianphone_c = mysql_fetch_row($physicianphone_c_query);
$url_physicianphone_c = $physicianphone_c[0];
echo $url_physicianphone_c;

$physicianfax_c_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `physicianfax_c`
FROM  `leads_cstm`
WHERE  `id_c` =  '$id[0]'");
$physicianfax_c = mysql_fetch_row($physicianfax_c_query);
$url_physicianfax_c = $physicianfax_c[0];
echo $url_physicianfax_c;

$physiciannpi_c_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `physiciannpi_c`
FROM  `leads_cstm`
WHERE  `id_c` =  '$id[0]'");
$physiciannpi_c = mysql_fetch_row($physiciannpi_c_query);
$url_physiciannpi_c = $physiciannpi_c[0];
echo $url_physiciannpi_c;

$primaryinsurance_c_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `primaryinsurance_c`
FROM  `leads_cstm`
WHERE  `id_c` =  '$id[0]'");
$primaryinsurance_c = mysql_fetch_row($primaryinsurance_c_query);
$url_primaryinsurance_c = $primaryinsurance_c[0];
echo $url_primaryinsurance_c;

$policynumber_c_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `policynumber_c`
FROM  `leads_cstm`
WHERE  `id_c` =  '$id[0]'");
$policynumber_c = mysql_fetch_row($policynumber_c_query);
$url_policynumber_c = $policynumber_c[0];
echo $url_policynumber_c;

$vendorid_c_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `vendorid_c`
FROM  `leads_cstm`
WHERE  `id_c` =  '$id[0]'");
$vendorid_c = mysql_fetch_row($vendorid_c_query);
$url_vendorid_c = $vendorid_c[0];
echo $url_vendorid_c;

$groupnumber_c_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `groupnumber_c`
FROM  `leads_cstm`
WHERE  `id_c` =  '$id[0]'");
$groupnumber_c = mysql_fetch_row($groupnumber_c_query);
$url_groupnumber_c = $groupnumber_c[0];
echo $url_groupnumber_c;

$pcn_number_c_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `pcn_number_c`
FROM  `leads_cstm`
WHERE  `id_c` =  '$id[0]'");
$pcn_number_c = mysql_fetch_row($pcn_number_c_query);
$url_pcn_number_c = $pcn_number_c[0];
echo $url_pcn_number_c;

$bin_number_c_query  =  mysql_query("SELECT  `bin_number_c`
FROM  `leads_cstm`
WHERE  `id_c` =  '$id[0]'");
$bin_number_c = mysql_fetch_row($bin_number_c_query);
$url_bin_number_c = $bin_number_c[0];
echo $url_bin_number_c;

if ($first_name != ''){ 
$date = date("m-d-y");
$time = time();
$blank = "";
$timestamp = 'A03-'.$date.'-'.$time;
$header = 'BeneficiaryFirstName,BeneficiaryLastName,BeneficiaryAddress1,BeneficiaryAddress2,BeneficiaryCity,BeneficiaryState,BeneficiaryZipCode,BeneficiaryPhone,BeneficiaryDOB,EMail,VendorCustomerID,DoctorNPI,DoctorName,DoctorAddress1,DoctorAddress2,DoctorCity,DoctorState,DoctorZipCode,DoctorPhone,DoctorFax,InsuranceType,InsuranceID,GroupID,BIN,PCN,InsuranceCompanyName,DailyTest,BeneficiaryGender,BestTimeToCall,SourceIP,CurrentMethod,LeadSource,Dependent,Password,ProductTypeID,Incentive';
$body = $url_first_name.','.$url_last_name.','.$url_primary_address_street.','.$blank.','.$url_primary_address_city.','.$url_primary_address_state.','.$url_primary_address_postalcode.','.$url_phone_home.','.$url_dateofbirth_c.','.$blank.','.$url_phone_home.','.$url_physiciannpi_c.','.$blank.','.$blank.','.$blank.','.$url_physiciancity_c.','.$url_physicianstate_c.','.$blank.','$url_physicianphone_c.','.$url_physicianfax_c.','.$url_primaryinsurance_c.','.$url_policynumber_c.','.$url_groupnumber_c.','.$url_bin_number_c.','.$url_pcn_number_c.','.$url_primaryinsurance_c.','.$url_testblood_c.','.$url_gender_c.','.$blank.','.$blank.','.$blank.','.$blank.','.$blank.','.$blank.','.$blank;
$filename = '/home/orsini/Ol-'.$timestamp.'.csv';
$handle = fopen($filename,'w');
fwrite($handle,$header."\n");
fwrite($handle,$body."\n");
fclose($handle);
mysql_query("UPDATE leads SET `status` = 'sold_orsini' WHERE `id` = '$id[0]'");
}
?>
```

Comment: Line 173 is `$date = date("m-d-y");` here. Sure you got the right code?

Comment: Could you please narrow your code to only include the lines immediately around the problem?

Comment: You could also fetch all variables at once, not with tedious and repetitive sql queries.

Comment: Btw: Your code is prone to SQL-Injections. Always make sure to sanitize input to your Database.

Answer (score 7):

You forgot one dot in your line with `$body = $url_first_name` at the very end:

`,'$url_physicianphone_c.'`

Comment: @Alex I just have thrown it into a file and compiled it. Afterwards jumped to the line and searched for missing dots.

Comment: Yeah that's what I did, the PHP warnings are usually spot on and straight forward enough.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use an IDE??

Here is your proper line with `$body`. You just missed a `.`.

```
$body = $url_first_name
        .','
        .$url_last_name
        .','
        .$url_primary_address_street
        .','
        .$blank
        .','
        .$url_primary_address_city
        .','
        .$url_primary_address_state.','.$url_primary_address_postalcode.','
        .$url_phone_home.','.$url_dateofbirth_c.','.$blank.','.$url_phone_home.','.$url_physiciannpi_c.','
        .$blank.','.$blank.','.$blank.','.$url_physiciancity_c.','.$url_physicianstate_c.','
        .$blank.','.$url_physicianphone_c . ',' . $url_physicianfax_c 
        .',' . $url_primaryinsurance_c . ','
        .$url_policynumber_c . ',' . $url_groupnumber_c . ',' . $url_bin_number_c . ',' . $url_pcn_number_c . ',' . $url_primaryinsurance_c . ',' . $url_testblood_c 
        . ',' . $url_gender_c . ',' . $blank . ',' . $blank . ',' . $blank . ',' . $blank . ',' . $blank . ',' . $blank . ',' . $blank;
```

Comment: Please refrain from insulting the asker.

Answer (score 0):

Found it `$url_physicianphone_c.` should be `.$url_physicianphone_c.` Now it has `.$url` and works.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve things if you consolidated all these queries into just a few. Use table joins to improve this. The DB will be faster at searching and sorting than your PHP.

That said you should also use the PHP CSV functions. Check it out here: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: You could also try using the implode and explode functions to build your CSV.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses everyone =)  I am just redoing a script from the previous tech here.  Didn't notice the dot heh am only using notepad++ but the file wasnt saved yet (so no color coordination).